# Story proofs in Combinatorics/Probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics, soft-question, self-learning, combinatorial-proofs

I have been recently been going through [Blitzstein](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VmkAAGOYCTORq1wxSQqy255qLJjTNvBI/edit) in an attempt to put my probability on a stronger foundation then it currently is. There is a large emphasis on the use of "story" proofs/definitions in the book

> A story proof is a proof by interpretation. For counting problems, this often means counting the same thing in two different ways, rather than doing tedious algebra. A story proof often avoids messy calculations and goes further than an algebraic proof toward explaining why the result is true. The word “story” has several meanings, some more mathematical than others, but a story proof (in the sense in which we’re using the term) is a fully valid mathematical proof. *- Introduction To Probability, page 20.*

I can understand the appeal since they bypass substantial amounts of algebra in certain cases.
However, thinking of the stories is not easy for all problems. And when one has finished the book, I am not sure how useful those skills will be.
(For some context, the earlier math/stat courses I had never emphasized the use of story proofs).

In general, how useful are "story" proofs beyond the context of the book I am currently doing (Blitzstein).

Comment: It is used in lots of places. It is a combinatorial argument, where we set up a bijection (or even a double-counting argument). EG Showing that $ \sum { n \choose i } = 2^n$, because the LHS represents the number of subsets of $i$ elements out of $n$, which is clearly $2^n$ (say by the rule of product).  $\quad$ EG sometimes people ask for a ["non-algebraic / combinatorial proof" on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=non-algebraic+combinatorial+proof), which could be an attempt to see if there's some underlying structure that the identity could surface.

Comment: It is extremely useful in *Stars and Bars* theory, as shown in 
[this article](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/).  The linked article is on the brillant.org website, which permits a free login.  Stars and Bars theory is also discussed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Answer (score 1):

I have been going through Blitzstein in a lot more detail. I was initially surprised by his emphasis on story proofs (mostly because my none of earlier courses/professors/books ever emphasized it).

But now that I went through a chapter in detail, I have found that the emphasis works wonders. It is a very different perspective from the one that you get from a mathematical/algebraic focus. Also, the entire book reads like a story (a good one!) where there is a lot of discussion happening.

In conjuction with a book/questions that focus on mathematical derivations, this book will work wonders.

Comment: Well, I think "tedious algebra" has its own beauty too

Comment: Agreed. That's why this book will do very in conjuction with another one that is more "math oriented". Unfortunately, I have seen too many courses that focus _only_ on the algebra.